# Как сделать, что бы информация из одного файла дублировась в несколько текстовых дукоментов, без определённых строчек

Tags: python, файлы

Нужен код на python который создавать несколько текстовых документов в которых будет написана только информация о букве v, и после буквы f создавать текстовый документ со следующей буквой v, информация взята из текстового документа `text.txt`:

```
text.txt:
v 123 123 123
v 123 123 123
v 123 123 123
vt 123 123 123
vn 123 123 123
f 12345 12345 12345
v 231 321 321
v 231 321 321
v 231 321 321
v 231 321 321
vt 321 312 321
vn 312 312 321
f 54321 54321 54321
```

Я смог только написать код который будет создавать новый текстовый документ, только с буквой v, но я не понимаю как сделать что бы каждый раз создавался новый текстовый документ для буквы v после буквы f но при этом что бы в новом текстовом документе тоже была информация о букве v

```py
if is_obj:
    w = open("mid.txt", "w")
    r = open(f"object.obj", "r")
    def treat():
        if line[0] == 'v':
            if line[1] == ' ':
                w.write(line)
    with open(f'object.obj') as read:
        for i in read:
            for line in read:
                treat()
```

Вот полный код программы:

```
import os.path

is_mtl = os.path.isfile("object.mtl")
is_obj = os.path.isfile("object.obj")

if is_mtl:
    a_file = open("object.mtl")
    lines_to_read = [6]

    for position, line in enumerate(a_file):

        if position in lines_to_read:
            color = line

    color = color[3:]
    color = color.replace("\n", "")

    floats = [float(x) for x in color.split()]

    color1 = floats[0]
    color2 = floats[1]
    color3 = floats[2]

    color1 = str(color1)
    color2 = str(color2)
    color3 = str(color3)
else:
    color1 = "1"
    color1 = "1"
    color1 = "1"

if is_obj:
    w = open("mid.txt", "w")
    r = open(f"object.obj", "r")
    def treat():
        if line[0] == 'v':
            if line[1] == ' ':
                w.write(line)
    with open(f'object.obj') as read:
        for i in read:
            for line in read:
                treat()


a_file.close()

w = open("out.mcfunction", "w")

with open('mid.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        cline = (line.replace("v", "~"))
        cline = cline.replace("\n", "")
        cline = cline[1:]
        cline = cline.replace(" ", " ~")
        cline = cline[1:]

        result = ("particle dust " + color1 + " " + color2 + " " + color3 + " 1 " + cline + " 0 0 0 0 1 force")

        print(result + "\n")
        w.write(result + "\n")
        
w.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Читаешь содержимое файла text.txt построчно. Когда обнаруживается строка, начинающаяся с 'f', создается новый текстовый документ (output_1.txt, output_2.txt, и так далее), в который записывается информация о букве 'v'. После завершения обработки файла, создается новый текстовый документ для сохранения оставшихся строк.

```
def create_new_file(file_content, file_number):
    with open(f"output_{file_number}.txt", "w") as new_file:
        for line in file_content:
            if line.startswith('v '):
                new_file.write(line)

def main():
    with open("text.txt", "r") as file:
        file_content = file.readlines()
        
        file_number = 1
        current_file_lines = []

        for line in file_content:
            if line.startswith('f '):
                # Создаем новый файл и записываем в него информацию о 'v'
                create_new_file(current_file_lines, file_number)
                current_file_lines = []  # Сбрасываем текущие строки
                file_number += 1  # Увеличиваем номер файла
            else:
                current_file_lines.append(line)

        # Обработка последнего файла
        create_new_file(current_file_lines, file_number)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Надеюсь правильно понял.

Comment: Это вроде работает но после того как обнаруживается строка, начинающаяся с 'f', у меня просто создаётся 3800 текстовых документов без какого либо содержимого

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то можно попробовать что-то такое

```py
import re

with open('text.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = [
        [elem + '\n' for elem in item.split('\n') if elem.startswith('v ')]
        for item in
        filter(bool, map(str.strip, re.split(r'^f.+?$', f.read(), flags=re.M)))
    ]
outfile_count = 1
for file_content in data:
    with open('output' + str(outfile_count) + '.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        outfile.writelines(file_content)
    outfile_count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Если верно уловил вашу мысль:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

current_document = []
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('f'):
        # Создание нового текстового документа
        with open(f'output_{line.strip()[1:]}.txt', 'w') as output_file:
            output_file.writelines(current_document)
        current_document = []
    current_document.append(line)

# Последний текстовый документ после последней буквы "f"
with open(f'output_last.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.writelines(current_document)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]